# For loop to check property is not undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make a for loop to check my class attributes, but I don't want to show those attributes what are undefined.

I have tried parse JSON with stringify and for each loop. But I've got the wrong generation.

```
  for(var alma in Category){
    if(typeof this.CatGroup !== "undefined"){
        return (  "Type=" +
      '"' +
      this.Type
```

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
 if(typeof obj[key] === 'undefined'){
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
```

```
<C undefined/>
```

With this for loop, I got only undefined.

Comment: can you add json that you are trying to work with

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to go about it:

```js
const json = {
  prop1: 'value1',
  prop2: 'value2',
  
  prop3: undefined,
}

console.log(
  Object.entries(json)
    .filter(([key, value]) => value !== undefined)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
    .join(', ')
)
```